# .htaccess: Pretty URLs and subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory, friendly-url

I do not use subfolders except for images but somehow Google find links to subfolders which results in an indexing error. Example: `https://example.com/mobile/page` - the mobile folder does not exist.

I have this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,B]
RewriteCond $1 !(\.(png|ico|css)|index\.php)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php? [L]
```

When requesting the above URL, the `index.php` is shown but without fetching the css file and images. I guess that it works from the folder "mobile" instead of the root folder.

How do I serve a 404 error to Google and redirect to the `index.php` in the root folder for real people following such a link?

I am not a programmer, I am only good at copying code :-/ I haven't been able to find the code necessary to solve the problem.

Comment: Well, you simply add a redirection rule that matches all requested URLs starting with `mobile/` and redirect those to wherever you want. You will find thousands of examples for redirection rules here on SO. And also taking a look into the documentation of the tool you are using helps. It is of excellent quality and comes with great examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: The problem is that it is not only a folder named "mobile" that Google visits; it is many different folders. Thus, I need a solution that works for any subfolder.

I am not a coder, I am not able to find a solution in the documentation. I have tried.

Comment: Then you need to setup a whitelist of folders that do exist (might well be "virtual" folders) and for that you allow requests to pass. For anything else you rewrite.

Comment: Since I am already testing whether a file exists in the code above, I tried to change the last rewriterule to include the domain and I added a 404 code:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://example.com/index.php? [R=404, L]

It seems to work, however, I am not sure whether it can have unwanted consequenses.

Comment: It did have unwanted consequenses. For some reason the first test went fine (cache?), but now I am redirected to the 404 page. Thus, I have removed R=404.

Comment: You are not testing whether a file exist in the code you posted. And a redirection with a http status 404 does not make any sense, where did you get _that_ from?

Comment: Please add your file system layout to the question. What folders do exist, what is stored where?

Comment: I thought the two condition lines checked if a requested file existed. Anyway, it does seem to work now all the error URLs in Googles Search consol are now redirected to the front page in the root folder, that is loading images and the css file too.

I only have two folders in the root folder: "billeder" (images) and "webp". Any files besides images are in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a mix of .htaccess and PHP. In case this can help others that get a lot of errors in Googles search console due to non-existing URLs somewhere on the internet:

In .htaccess I have this:

RewriteCond $1 !(.(png|ico|css)|index.php)$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/nopage? [L]

That redirects the non-existing URLs to "nopage". In PHP I catch the "nopage" and serve an error page for the human visitor with a 404 header for Googles search bot:

header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 404 Not Found");

I can understand from arkascha's answers that my .htaccess code does not check whether a file exists, however, it works like a charm.

Comment: A much easier solution may be to edit the standard 404 page and let that catch non-existing pages. I do not recall why I back in the days decided do it this way.